# Saving foreign key value in relevant table - Laravel Resource Control

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-resource

I have 2 tables: Manufacturers and Brands.

Manufacturers: 
fields : id and manufacturer

Brands:
fields : many other fields with 'manufacturer_id' field which indexes "Manufacturers" table's 'id'.

I have a select box which supposed to load manufacturer field from Manufacturers table.
When storing in db i need to store the 'id' of Manufacturer in Brands table.

It is a one to one relation but i do not know how to do it with Laravel Resource Controller Model.. CRUD

I have setup foreign keys also

This is BrandsContoller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Brands;
use App\Manufacturer;
use App\Contents;
use App\Usage;
use App\Type;
use App\SideEffect;

class BrandsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $brand_names = Brands::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('brands.index', compact('brand_names'))->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        // $manufacturerList = Manufacturer::find(2);
        //$brand = Manufacturer::find(3)->brand;
        return view('brands.create', compact('brand'));
    }

    public function test($id){

        $manufacturerss = Manufacturer::find($id);
        return view('test', compact('manufacturer'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // request()->validate([
        //     'brand_name' => 'required',
        //     'short_description' => 'required',
        //     'manufacturers_id' => 'required',
        //     'contents_id' => 'required',
        //     'usages_id' => 'required',
        //     'types_id' => 'required',
        //     'photo' => 'required',
        //     'side_effects_id' => 'required',
        //     'common_use' => 'required',
        //     'dosage_directions' => 'required',
        //     'precautions' => 'required',
        //     'contradictions' => 'required',
        //     'possible_side_effects' => 'required',
        //     'drug_interactions' => 'required',
        //     'missed_dose' => 'required',
        //     'overdose' => 'required',
        //     'storage' => 'required',
        //     'discalimer' => 'required',
        // ]);
        // $manufacturer->brands()->save($manufacturer);
        // $manufacturer->manufacturer()->associate($manufacturer)->save();

        Brands::create($request->all());
        // $brand = new Brands;
        // $brand -> manufacturer_id = $data-> manufacturer_id;
        // $brand -> save();
        // @foreach($manufacturerList as $item)
        // {

        //     $brand->manufacturer()->create(['manufacturer_id' => $item]);

        // }
        // @endforeach

        return redirect()->route('brands.index')->with('success', 'Brand created succesfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $brand_name = Brands::find($id);
        return view('brands.show',compact('brand_name'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $brand_name = Brands::find($id);
        return view('brands.edit', compact('brand_name'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'brand_name' => 'required',
            'short_description' => 'required',
            'manufacturers_id' => 'required',
            'contents_id' => 'required',
            'usages_id' => 'required',
            'types_id' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'required',
            'side_effects_id' => 'required',
            'common_use' => 'required',
            'dosage_directions' => 'required',
            'precautions' => 'required',
            'contradictions' => 'required',
            'possible_side_effects' => 'required',
            'drug_interactions' => 'required',
            'missed_dose' => 'required',
            'overdose' => 'required',
            'storage' => 'required',
            'discalimer' => 'required',
        ]);
        Brands::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('brands.index')->with('success', 'Brand updated succesfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Brands::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('brands.index')->with('success', 'Brand sucessfully deleted');
    }
}
```

This is Brands Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brands extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'brands';
    protected $fillable = ['brand_name','short_description','content_id','usage_id','type_id','photo','side_effect_id','common_use','dosage_directions','precautions','contradictions','possible_side_effects','drug_interactions','missed_dose','overdose','storage','discalimer'];

    public function manufacturer()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Manufacturer');
    }
}
```

This is Manufacturer Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Manufacturer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'manufacturers';
    protected $fillable = ['manufacturer'];

    public function brand()
    {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Brands','manufacturer_id');
    }
}
```

This is my front end which has the select box:

```
<strong>MANUFACTURER : </strong>

      <br>
      <select id="manufacturers" name="manufacturers" class="form-control item_view" placeholder="Please choose" onchange="">
      <option>Select Manufacturer</option>
      <option value="0">Add New</option>


      <option value="" >test</option>



      </select>
```

I am getting the correct values in tinker, but i do not know how to save in db..

Any help much appreciated....

Comment: Looks like there are typos in the store and update methods on your Brand controller. You are referring to "manufacturers_id" instead of "manufacturer_id". Also, your input is named "manufacturers", not "manufacturers_id". Both of these issues will keep your ID from getting into the database. I see tons of other typos, such as in the "test" method, as well. I have a feeling you are just not passing the information consistently between model, view and controller.

Answer (score 0):

When using Model::create() and Model::update() methods, the data will be filtered using the fillable or guarded attributes on your model.

As your Brand model doesn't have the 'manufacturers_id' inside the fillable, this field will not be saved on the database.

Also, you need to name your select input to "manufacturers_id" to send the correct attribute to the backend.

Tip:

- I recommend the usage of [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) in your models, database, and relationships. Eg: use "Brand" model, not "Brands" Model, and  manufacturer_id, not manufacturers_id. Using these conventions, Laravel Eloquent ORM can easily manage your queries and the code can be more clear and concise.